# java database connectivity with live server using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, connectivity

Here i am trying to connect my java file to mysql running on my live server..but after execution i got error "packet for query is too large"..i visited other post related to the question then i got the information to increase the max_allowed_size should be greater than the packet size..even after doing the same i am not able to resolve the error.

code that i tried.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MySql {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://web-address:port-number/db";
    String username ="uname";
    String password = "pwd";

    Connection dbCon = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    //System.out.println("connection successful"); 
   try {
        //getting database connection to MySQL server
        dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

         System.out.println("connection successful"); 


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 

}  
}
```

error while execution is 
packet for query is too large (4739923>1048576). you can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.

Comment: Can you run this SQL command somewhere: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_size'. This shows if you really changed the value of max_allowed_size.

Comment: And usually after changing the variable you should restart the server. Did you do that?

Comment: I increase the size of max_allowed_packet=15M..but its not working again giving the same error..

Comment: yes i restart the server...after executing the SQL command SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'MAX%' ..its showing me the changed size of packet..

Comment: If it still gives exactly the same error, then the value of max_allowed_size isn

Comment: If it gives exactly the same error, then value of max_allowed_packet haven't been changed. Are you sure that the value is changed?

Comment: when i execute the sql command then it shows the changed size of packet...that means the value of max_allowed_packet=15728640

Comment: Can you please give the exact error?

Comment: What are the Statement and ResultSet variables for? Are you really showing us the complete code you used?

Comment: packet for query is too large (4739923>1048576). you can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.

Comment: actually the problem is in the connection..not able to connect to the server..apart from this if i am trying to connect using php i am successfully login to the mysql running on server...and able to fetch the table info...but here in java the connection is not established...

Comment: finally i got d solution...using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759418/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception/27303694#27303694  thank u..