# Error 'Packet for query is too large' when I tried to make a query on my website

Tags: java-8, mariadb, apache-cayenne, max-allowed-packet

Again I need your help. 
I'm trying to put my java web site online.

**What I use :**

- MySQL server : command line mysql -V, **result** : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
- Cayenne
- Debian server
- Java (Vaadin)

> Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576). You can change this
>   value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

**What I tried :**

**1.** Like the error said, I tried to change the value on the server by doing :

- Log on my server
- Connect to MySQL with : `mysql -u root`
- Enter : `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`
- then, restart the server with : `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

But I still have the error.

**2.** I took a look to : [How to change max_allowed_packet size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size)

But, When I did the `nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`, the file looks like (I don't have any [mysql]) :

```
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Nov 10 23:57:02 2017 from 82.236.220.195
root@XXXX:~# nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  GNU nano 2.7.4               File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf                Modified

# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

In mysql, the folders/files in the 'mysql' folder is :

[image]

Any hint will be very appreciate! 
Thanks

**EDIT:** In `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`, I changed :

1. `max_allowed_packet = 1073741824`
2. `max_connections = 100000`

and I added : `net_buffer_length   = 1048576`

For info : 
In my workbench, I can see the server variables : 
[image]

EDIT2 : Now, when I select the variable in command line on the server, I have :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet;
+-----------------------------+
| @@global.max_allowed_packet |
+-----------------------------+
|                  1073741824 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**SOLUTION Because the error was not explicit.**

Thanks to [com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759418/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception)

My cayenne configuration was :

```
<url value="jdbc:mysql://IPADDRESS:22/DBBASENAME" />
<login userName="ServerUserName" password="ServerPassword" />
```

But it should be :

```
<url value="jdbc:mysql://IPADDRESS/DBBASENAME" />
<login userName="MYSQLUserName" password="MYSQLPassword" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it in `my.cnf`, then restart mysqld.

Better yet, put it in a file under `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/`, and specify the section:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824
```

What you did (`SET`) went away when you restarted.  Even so, it only applied to connections that logged in after doing the `SET`.

Comment: Hi @Rick James, Thanks for your help. But, I think I did what you said. In your first point : 'change it in `my.cnf`, I tried but like I said, i don't have  any [mysqld], I put the same lines you wrote in the `my.cnf` and restart it : without success. Then, you said, put a file under `/ect/mysql/mariadb.conf.d`, like I said in my post, I edit `50-server.cnf`. Should I create a new file?? if yes, what should be the file name? Thanks

Comment: Assuming `...d` is a directory, create any filename you like (I use my initials + `.cnf`) and put those 2 lines in it.  `50-server.cnf` should be fine.

Comment: not working :(. when I put it in a new bob.cnf, I didn't have any change (I still have the error). This is very strange, isn't it??

Comment: I updated the post with screen shot (see EDIT1 and EDIT2), as you can see, I have your max_allowed_packet, it's persistent, when I restart mysql, max_allowed_packet is the same... But I still have the issue...

Comment: I checked : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet, My version is : 10.1.23-MariaDB. When I read the documentation, '1048576 (1MB) <= MariaDB 10.1.6'. the number seems to be the limit in the error...

Comment: You did restart after adding `bob.cnf`?  1M is the _default_ value.  The "Range" is much larger.  Let's try something:  also add `group_concat_max_len = 1111` to the file; restart; login; do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group%'.  See if it is still the default of 1024, or if it changed to 1111.

Comment: I'll try ! I take a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759418/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception. It's can be my configuration??

Comment: I still have 1024

Comment: Okay....... the error was not explicit at all!!!! It was not an error with the max_allowed_packet, the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759418/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception was right. My error was in the cayenne configuration exactly like @mathheadinclouds told...

Comment: I accepted your answer because 99% of time it's the solution.